# Homomorphisms between tensor products

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

How would one construct an injective $R$-module homomorphism $r$ between tensor product of $M^*$ and $N$ to $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$ such that
$$(r(f \otimes n))(m) = f(m)n$$

Comment: Is $R$ commutative?

Answer (score 2):

The map $M^* \times N \to \hom(M,N),\, (f,n) \mapsto f(-)n := (m \mapsto f(m)n)$ is $R$-bilinear (check this!). By the universal property of the tensor product, it induces a homomorphism $M^* \otimes N \to \hom(M,N)$.

Remark: This homomorphism isn't injective nor surjective in general. The image consists of those homomorphisms which factor through a finitely generated free module. If $M$ is finitely generated projective, then it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

You just did*. Now all you have to do is show that it really is well-defined, is a homomorphism, and is injective.

*: (recall that a function can be defined by specifying its value on a set of points, and a homomorphism from a module can be defined by specifying its value on a generating set)

Comment: ... and verifying that the homomorphism respects any relations among generators... sometimes an awkward thing, thus, we'd hope to be mapping "free" objects, or "universal" objects, so that there are no subtle relations to check.

Comment: how exactly would u verify the linear properties?

Comment: @user: Write down the equation you need to prove: it pretty much writes itself from there, if you apply the linear properties for the operators you already know.

Comment: so i just use f1 tensor n1, f2 tensor n2 to prove it preserves addition, and rf tensor n, where r is a ring for multiplication?

Comment: -1 since this "answer" totally ignores the relations. And it is misleading / impossible to show "by hand" that the map is a homomorphism. Besides, the homomorphism won't be injective in general.

Comment: @Martin: Checking that a map is "well-defined" *means* checking the relations. And I'm not sure what trouble *you* have showing it's a homomorphism "by hand", since the only things that need to be checked are the bilinearity relations of the tensor product. (which also settles well-definedness)

Comment: Yes, I know that. So why don't you say so in your answer? Anyway.